# django chain select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

[django-smart-selects](http://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) is an elegant solution that enables Django developers to have chained select inputs in their forms. But as reported by developers in its list of issues, it does not work well when used in formsets.

The javascript it renders is tied to the id of the "chained field" right in the model definition.

How do you think this can be made to work when used in formsets? I think the render method of the widget (please see the django-smart-selects code) needs to somehow be made aware of formsets (and ideally, form prefixes). But how?

Comment: Well, to make it work with formsets, I plan to render the forms/formsets and teh required javascript manually. Just looking for some pointers on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and it works --- In the widgets.py file of django-smart-selects code, simply copy the section that deals with rendering javascript and delete it from the file. Remove the line that concatenates this (now deleted) javascript to the output.

For your formsets, do the complete rendering yourself. That is, in your template don't just do {{ form }} or {{ formset }} or whatever, but explicitly lay out all individual fields by doing {{ form.field }} in a {% for form in formset.forms %} loop.

Paste the javascript code that you copied over from widgets.py and customize it with the IDs in the javascript with {{ form.field.html_name }}

Write in your own customized urls in the javascript, following the pattern in the code.

Voila!

Comment: The only problem was that the javascript was not getting the IDs right. Your "solution" involves taking out a lot of auto-magic and addresses the core issue. Good one. I guess the real gem here is the {{ form.field.html_name }}.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use the formset's name/id/index in the element ID that is used by javascript, that way they'll still be unique