# Django: most efficient way to query many records?

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a table with a few thousands records (products). Each product has a 4 different categories:

```
CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 CAT4
```

I wonder if is there a method, or what is the best practice, to dynamically retrive the available categories based on the categories already selected (using Ajax).
Example:

if `CAT1 = green` all the products with `CAT1 = green` will have a series of `CAT2` categories and so on. I would like to know which are the CAT2 CAT3 CAT4 categories whose products match `CAT1 = green`. Once I set a value or `CAT2` as well I would like to do the same based on `CAT1 && CAT2` values.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand your question - do you want to find what categories objects with `CAT1 = green` have? Maybe add a sample set of products, and then a sample result set that you're aiming for.

Comment: What code have you tried?  What problem does that code have?

Comment: Are there any relationships established between these models?  Post your models if you can.

Comment: I wrote down a simple data sample in my answer below

Comment: Can I ask you one thing: what do you do if your product belongs to five categories? How do you encode that in your system?

Comment: each category is a foreign_key so accepting only one value. each product has four foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a technique commonly known as "select chaining" or "chained selects".

You can use some fairly simple javascript for this as shown in the answer to [How to limit choice field options based on another choice field in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796466/how-to-limit-choice-field-options-based-on-another-choice-field-in-django-admin/796567#796567)

You can also use a prepackaged solution such as [django-smart-selects](http://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/tree/master/smart_selects/) (found via the SO answer to [django chain select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914358/django-chain-select))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. The Chained select only works partially as I don't have a hierarchical structure.
Here is an example of data:

```
PRODUCT 1
CAT1 = vegetables
CAT2 = heavy
CAT3 = green

PRODUCT 2
CAT1 = vegetable
CAT2 = light
CAT3 = red

PRODUCT 3
CAT1 = diary
CAT2 = heavy
CAT3 = red
```

In my template I would like to make a system so that when the users choose `CAT1 = vegetables` they see `CAT2` options to be heavvy and light while if they choose `CAT1 = diary` the only option for `CAT2` is heavy and so on.

My way to go would be to get a json of the entire product table and look for the available values once a category has been selected... but the products table comprises thousands of items and Im quite sure it will slow down the entire app.
There is something similar in the admin page when you add the Filter function (`list_filter`) as it shows only the fields that have some entries in them.

THANKS!

Comment: If you wish to update your question, the correct way to do it is to edit the question itself, not provide an answer. Please consider deleting this answer and editing the question itself instead. Thanks!