# Filtering a django choicefield in admin form on the basis of a value of another choicefield in the same form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

In the admin form, how do you filter a django choicefield on the basis of value of another choicefield.

For example, if a choicefield is having "fruits" and "vegetables", then on selection of fruits, the second choicefield should have "apple,pear,orange" etc.Similarly one selection of vegetables the field should show "brinjal,lady finger,cabbage"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd have to use JavaScript if you want dynamic filtering without a page refresh.

If the user can somehow submit the form and you have a chance to re-display the form with filtered choices, you can always modify the `form.fields['my_field'].choices` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish that with grouped selects in [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). The default is outputting a drop down menu. And you should be able to [modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914358/django-chain-select) to output radio buttons instead.